# How to create new object of Generic Type T from a parametrized List<T>

Tags: java, generics

I have following java sample class:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static <T> void method(List<T> objects) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
            // Create new object of the same class
            T obj = (T) objects.get(i).getClass().newInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

It is producing a compiler warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from capture#1-of ? extends Object to T

I can perfectly obtain the exact T object, if I just do:

```
T obj = objects.get(i);
```

Which it knows perfectly is of Type T.

Why I am not able to create a new instance of that class? How could I fix it?

**(I am not looking for a response of type: 'Add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")')**

Comment: What if you change the declaration to `<T extends Foo>`, where `Foo` is whichever class or interface defines the `newInstance()` method?

Comment: I want it totally generic. There is no "Foo". I might call method with List<A> or List<B> or List<C>... etc. Should be no more relation among them than extending Object.class

Comment: Note that the `Class#newInstance` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance())) is **deprecated** (since java 9). Use `Constructor.newInstance` instead.

Comment: "Why I am not able to create a new instance of that class?" but you are. You're just getting a warning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because `getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends Object>`. You cannot (safely) cast the wildcard `?` to anything, not even a generic class type. This is a limitation of Java Generics. But since you can be sure this warning is not a problem you can safely ignore or suppress it.

---

But here is a workaround, many applications and libraries do this:

```
public static <T> void method(List<T> objects, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        // Create new object of the same class
        T obj = clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Generics are erased at runtime. So invoking  `getClass()` on a declared `T` element of the list returns a `<? extends Object>` class instance.

`Object.getClass()` states indeed :

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the
>   erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is
>   called.

To invoke `newInstance()` and create an instance of `T` you need to know the `Class` instance which you want to instantiate but note that the `List` can contain any subclass of `T`, so passing a class as parameter may not be enough.

For example :

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Lion());
list.add(new Rabbit());
list.add(new Turtle());
```

Which one invoked now ?

```
method(list, Lion.class); 
method(list, Rabbit.class);
method(list, Turtle.class);
```

No one as anyone will compile ! So it is clearly not enough.
So I think that it makes more sense to keep your original code by suppressing the warning. In this way you ensure that you will create an instance of the same class that the actual element in the list :

```
public static <T> void method(List<T> objects) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        // Create new object of the same class
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T obj = (T) objects.get(i).getClass().newInstance();
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why I am not able to create a new instance of that class?

You are. Your code will compile and it will work as you expect, but the compiler isn't 100% sure of that because of type erasure which is why you get a warning. The important thing to note here is that warnings are not the same as errors.

> (I am not looking for a response of type: 'Add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")')

If you look at any Java code base that uses generics and reflection in conjunction with each other, you will see suppressed warnings for type safety. That's just a fact of life, unfortunately.

Comment: I think the real question is why he even needs to cast. The method declares the return type as `T` for `Class<T>`. So one would assume it returns `T` and not `Object`.

Comment: @Zabuza but `objects.get(i).getClass()` doesn't return `Class<T>`.

Comment: @Kayaman I know, but I think that's what one would assume. Thus, OP asked the question.